# How to plot multiple LME residual plots in one device

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot multiple diagnostic LME plots showing standardized residuals versus fitted values in one device.
I tried the usual par(mfrow=c(2,2)) but plotting LME residuals with the plot(lme) command does not work, as the full device is used instead.

I wanted to use facet_wrap or facet_grid from ggplot2 but it does not know how to deal with models and plot residuals automatically.

Here is some test code:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
treatment=factor(c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4)))
response=rnorm(12,2,1)
explanatory=rnorm(12,4,1)
test.lme=lme(response~explanatory,random=~1|treatment)
test.lm=lm(response~explanatory)
plot(test.lme)
```

for comparison:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(response~explanatory)
plot(test.lm)
```

works fine.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stuff from the `grid()` package to set up viewports, etc., but the easiest way is with the `grid.arrange()` function from the `gridExtra` package:

```
library('nlme')
set.seed(101)
treatment <- factor(c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4)))
response <- rnorm(12,2,1)
explanatory <- rnorm(12,4,1)
test.lme <- lme(response~explanatory,random=~1|treatment)
library('gridExtra')
p1 <- plot(test.lme)
p2 <- plot(form=sqrt(abs(resid(.)))~fitted(.),test.lme)
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

You can specify numbers of rows and columns, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Why do you suggest using absolute values of residuals in your code? Wouldn't it prevent us from detecting asymmetries of residuals?

Comment: I was mimicking the behaviour of `plot.lm()` to some extent.  The plot of sqrt(abs(residuals)) vs. fitted is called a *scale-location* plot, and is optimized for detecting heteroscedasticity ...

Answer (score 0):

There is now a function ggplot::autoplot() that will accept model objects and plot all four diagnostics in facets.

Edit: Oops, it is actually in the `ggfortify` package and apparently masks `ggplot2::autoplot()` when loaded, which is why I thought it was in ggplot2.

Comment: Objects of type lm and lme are not accepted by autoplot(), I just tried it.